# how to do testing (unit/functional/integration) for a web app->Spring MVC+Bootstrap

Tags: spring-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I am creating a web app using Spring MVC for back end (as an API) and this API is accessed by JQuery code in a Twitter Bootstrap template.

How do I do testing for such a web app? Do I test first the Spring API using Spring's built in testing support, and then again test the HTML Web App using Qunit/other Javascript testing framework? Is there any faster/easier/recommended approach for testing such web apps?